# not able to define service contract in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have the below mentioned code and i need to put it in a service contract so that it will be exposed for consumption

```
           ListTemplateCollection ltc = web.ListTemplates;
           var listTemplates = clientContext.LoadQuery(
           ltc.Where(p => p.InternalName == name));
           clientContext.Load(ltc);
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
           return listTemplates.FirstOrDefault();
```

---

I have defined the above code but still i am not able to make a call.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you detail how your binding look, and how you are invoking it?

Comment: I have this public method, now I want to make this callable from .svc file,please help me to get this done,im struggling to put the correct thing in operationcontract.

Comment: it would be great if you could share operation contract and binding configuration, you managed to write so far.

Comment: hi Brijesh, i am not not able to copy paste all source codes as space restriction applies, can you pls pass on your email id - so that i can send the details and you can look into it, its urgent - thanks for your help - kajal

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to create operation contract.

Suppose your "ListTemplateCollection"  is collection of class ListTemplate then declare this Class  with DataContract and Its properties with DataMember attribute.

Your operation contract is like ListTemplate FindTemplate(string templateName);

Comment: we have few methods already defined in the service class, now i want to invoke them in the .svc file and define the service contract in the interface file, can i please have your email id so that i can forward the source code, as i am not able to put it here due to restrictions. thank you again kajal

Comment: If I understand you right, you have already created Service contract, now you want to deploy on IIS or local host as SVC file and consume it. You have to create a WCF service application for this. You can select it from visual studio --new project--web--wcf service application. There is SVC file there. In svc. CS file Contract is defined in Interface. If you already developed this (contract library) then just mention this config.. <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="xxxService" %> on SVC file with adding reference of your library.

Comment: hi,yes i am able to consume the web services successfully, thanks